# Does @Description have anything to do with junit tests? Is it just a chatGPT bug and there isn't annotation for long description e.g. given_when_then?

Tags: java, junit4, junit5

I wanted to add a long description to my tests that would be visible to the person running it.
I am using java 17 (17.0.4) with Maven and IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.4 (Community Edition) IDE.
I wrote a test in jUnit 5 using the @Description annotation (jdk.jfr.Description), but I don't see its effect anywhere.
Where can I see the @Description annotation effect?

**---> Reply from discussion:** The jdk.jfr module is related to the JDK Flight Recorder tool and it not connect with jUnit tests. To add a longer description to your tests, you can use @DisplayName or your own annotation with DisplayNameGenerator or just your own annotation. Javadoc is also used for description, but it isn't visible dynamic in the IDE.

I tried to implement @Description annotations (org.junit.jupiter.api.Description) but it does not exist or is not available. ---> Reply from discussion: this annotation doesn't exist, it's just chatGPT search bug.

**Implementation steps:**

1. Added the dependency in the dependencies section of the pom.xml
   file:

```
`<dependencies>
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
             <version>5.9.2</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
             <version>5.9.2</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
             <version>1.9.2</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
             <version>5.9.2</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
             <version>1.3.2</version>
         </dependency>
         <!-- end -->
    </dependencies>`
```

2. I run Load Maven Changes
3. I made a class:

---

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Dog {
    private String name;
    private Float weight;

    public Dog(String name, double weight) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Dog)) return false;
        Dog dog = (Dog) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, dog.name) && Objects.equals(weight, dog.weight);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, weight);
    }
}
```

---

4. I made a test class:

---

```
import jdk.jfr.Description;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class DogTest {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("compare object")
    @Description("Test should compare object")
    void testComparisonOfDogObjects() {
        Dog dog = new Dog("Fido", 5.25);
        Dog dogClone = new Dog("Fido", 5.25);
        assertEquals(dog, dogClone);
    }
}
```

---

5. I run the test testComparisonOfDogObjects() and I see name of test
   ("compare object") in the run's tab. But I don't see anywhere
   description. I check all tabs.

**MY QUESTION: Where I can see this description?**

---

**I tried to implement @Description annotations by:**

- ** selection from suggested annotations by the IDE - (jdk.jfr.Description)** ---> Reply from discussion: The jdk.jfr module is related to the JDK Flight Recorder tool and it not connect with jUnit tests.

Everything compiles but I don't see the description set in @Description anywhere.

- Find JAR on web for (org.junit.jupiter.api.Description)

ERROR: No libraries found for 'org.junit.jupiter.api.Description'
I also checked on the website if there is such an annotation - there is not:
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/package-summary.html
---> Reply from discussion: this annotation doesn't exist, it's just chatGPT search bug.

- Add jUnit 4 dependencies for (org.junit.runner.Description)
  ---> Reply from discussion: It's related to JUnit test runner from jUnit 4, we can merge jUnit 4 and jUnit 5. This seems complicated to me and I think a better solution is customize the @DisplayName annotation or create your own annotation with DisplayNameGenerator as you wrote.
  https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/

Comment: What do you expect this `@Description` annotation to do? Why do you think JUnit 5 would understand such an annotation?

Comment: You're right the annotation is available even when I remove everything from pom.xml - there is no binding to jUnit5. I was looking for a way to implement this annotation in a different way -> the chat found an implementation of import org.junit.jupiter.api (so I somehow suggested it) - I don't know where because there was no such entry in the given pages. I have not been able to find such an implementation.

Comment: However, I found information on the website https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/ and there is a TEST_MECHANISM field, but this implementation did not work either. However, the default jdk.jfr.Description compiles. I'd like to know what it is for...

Comment: The [`jdk.jfr`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/jdk.jfr/module-summary.html) module is related to the [JDK Flight Recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Flight_Recorder) tool. It's not related to unit testing, let alone JUnit.

Comment: It turns out that the only way to add a description to the tests are comments or javadoc or your own annotation. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's one way, though that won't show up in any reports. The other option is to make use  of `@DisplayName` and make the name descriptive "enough" for your needs. A third option might be to create your own `@Description` annotation as well as a [`DisplayNameGenerator`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/DisplayNameGenerator.html) that can read from it, possibly in combination with `@DisplayName`, to generate a more descriptive "name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen, there's no `Description` annotation in JUnit, and using JFR's annotation has no effect on a JUnit test.

The closest functionality is available by JUnit `DisplayName` annotation that you're already use it, and would cause the test runner to use the string given there instead of the method's name.